# React native webview getting closed when website asks for location permission in ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

Loading a website that asks for location into the react native webview , when location permission prompt appears on the app it closes the webview.

```
  return (
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={{
        uri: 'https://www.swiggy.com',
      }}
    />
  );
```